# Trace32 emulation installation

Tags: debugging, trace32, lauterbach

I have at my disposition a `MPC5566` evaluation board, I installed the software `Trace32` for debugging purpose with the right debugger from `lauterbach`, the problem is that I can't find the right `exe` for the board i'm using, even after i tried an upload for the software, i used the `DVD SP1`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your target CPU is part of the PowerPC family. Thus you need "TRACE32 for PowerPC".

Use `t32mppc.exe` from c:\T32\bin\windows 
or 
c:\T32\bin\windows64, if your Windows is a 64-bit variant.